# User defined function to automate an existing wrangling process for multiple csv files

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, dplyr, user-defined-functions

Objective:  To write a `user defined function` that automates the `wrangling process` for multiple `.csv` files.

I have 3 `.csv files`namely, `Finland_caucasian.csv`, `Mexico_hispanic.csv` & `Jamaica_black.csv`.

Using `Finland_caucasian.csv` as an example, the dataframe looks like this :

```
date <- rep('1999',9)
cityID <- c(1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1002,1005,1005,1005)
country <- rep('FIN'9)
name <- rep('caucasian',9)
prov_code <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,3)
class <- c(1,2,5,1,2,5,1,2,5)
gender <- c('M','M','F','F','F','M','F','M','M')
savings_month1 <-c(100.12,105.11,109.11,94.13,34.00,201.91,154.39,212.76,233.48)
savings_month2 <-c(110.15,115.12,193.21,194.13,334.50,21.13,164.19,292.67,235.85)
savings_month3 <-c(109.15,159.12,199.22,199.18,339.59,291.95,169.94,299.78,233.22)
data<- data.frame(date,cityID,name,country,prov_code,class,gender,savings_month1,savings_month2,savings_month3)
data
```

The raw wrangling process (without a user-defined function) looks like this :

```
# template for the user-defined function- should import csv files in a folder
#############################################################################
data_wrangler <- function(input_multi_csvfiles){
   # import each csv file
   for(files in filenames){
  # wrangle process
  }
}

# test code 
data_wrangler(files in folder path)

################################################################################################
# code for the wrangling process
library(dplyr)
#Step I: import all three files in R
 data = read.csv("filepath//file_name.csv") # 'Finland_caucasian.csv','Mexico_hispanic.csv' and 'Jamaica_black.csv'

#Step II : select the desired column names 
df <- data%>%select(date:gender,savings_month1:savings_month3) # I used column index `:` because the other csv files might have undesired columns in between. 

#Step III: check the unique prov_code, country,name, class
print(unique(df$prov_code))
print(unique(df$country))
print(unique(df$name))
print(unique(df$class))

#Step IV: filter the df based on 'class'
# Here, I will like to automate to reflect the unique countries ( FIN, MEX and JAM) instead of manually entering the countries three times, likewise for the name column- caucasian, hispanic and black
country_name_df <-subset(df,country == 'FIN' & name == 'caucasian' & class >= 1 & class <= 5) # in the other csv files class ranges from 0 to 8, but I want to filter for ONLY class ranging from 1 to 5

#Step V:  Paste filtered class on each of the column names
df10 <- filter(country_name_df,class == 1)
#paste the filtered class condition to the column names 
colnames(df10) <- paste('1',colnames(df10),sep = '_')
df11 <- filter(country_name_df,class == 2)
#paste the filtered class condition to the column names 
colnames(df11) <- paste('2',colnames(df11),sep = '_')
df12 <- filter(country_name_df,class == 5)
#paste the filtered class condition to the column names 
colnames(df12) <- paste('5',colnames(df12),sep = '_')

#Step VI:  column bind or merge df10, df11 and df12
 df15 <- cbind(df10,df11,df12)
#check for content of class column of df15
unique(df15$`5_prov_code`)

#Step VII: final wrangle for the dataframe
df20<- df15%>%select(`1_date`:`1_gender`)
df30 <-select(df15,contains("month")) # select all columns containing string 'month'  example '1_savings_month1', '3_savings_month2' etc
target <- df15$`1_prov_code`
final_df <- cbind(df20,df30,target)

#Step VIII: export each of the final_df as csv files 
# wrangled_Finland+caucasian.csv, wrangled_Mexico+hispanic.csv,wrangled_Jamaica+black.csv
write.csv(final_df,'wrangled_FIN+caucasian.csv',row.names = FALSE)
```

I am open to other ideas.  Thanks

Update for Akrun

I ran your code (see below) .

[image]

error i got

[image]

Update 2: sequence of column names after `gender_1` should look like this  `savings_month1_1`, `savings_month1_2`,`savings_month1_5`, `savings_month2_1`,`savings_month2_2`,`savings_month2_5`,`savings_month3_1`,`savings_month3_2,savings_month3_5`

[image]

Update 3: error after changing `savings_month1:savings_month3`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have 3 files in the working directory, read those in a `list` with `map`, do the `select` and `filter` step and use either `group_by` on 'class' or `split` into a `list` of data.frames

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
df_list <- map(files, ~ read_csv(.x) %>%
               select(date:gender, savings_month1:savings_month3) %>%
               filter(country == 'FIN', name == 'caucasian', 
                    class >= 1 , class <= 5) %>%
               group_by(class))
```

---

if we need a function with parameters

```
f1 <- function(filenm, cntrynm, racenm, class_low, class_high) {
      out <- readr::read_csv(filenm) %>%
       dplyr::select(date:gender, savings_month1_1:savings_month3_5) %>%
           dplyr::filter(country == cntrynm, name == racenm, 
                    class >= class_low , class <= class_high) %>%

        dplyr::mutate(rn = data.table::rowid(class)) %>% 
        tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = class, 
           values_from = setdiff(names(.), c("rn", "class"))) %>%
       dplyr::select(-rn) %>% 
       dplyr::select(ends_with('_1'), contains('month')) %>% 
       dplyr::rename(target = prov_code_1)               
       readr::write_csv(out, glue::glue("wrangled_{cntrynm}+{racenm}.csv"))
       return(out)
}
```

Then, we apply the function with the parameters in `pmap`

```
pmap(list(filenm = files, cntrynm = c("FIN", "MEX", "JAM"),
           racenm = c("caucasian", "hispanic", "jamaican"),
              class_low  = c(1, 1, 1), class_high = c(5, 5, 5)), f1)
```

Comment: How can we automate your code for other csv files with `country =='MEX',  name =='hispanic' ` or where `country == 'JAM' and name == 'black'`?

Comment: @nasa313 do you need the function including the `map` or just the filter and select steps?  also, what names do you want as output csv files i.e. is it same or different?  Is there any other parameters going into the function other than file names

Comment: I think you skipped `steps V - VIII`, I  want to automate the entirety of `step I ` to `step VIII` .  `Step V` and `Step VII` are crucial to the desired wrangled result. check `step VIII` in my code for desired output files.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt- looks good. However, I think you skipped `steps V, VI and VII` please can you include them in your code?

Comment: @nasa313 that V step looks to be not needed as I earlier mentioned you can use `group_by` or `split`.

Comment: @nasa313 or may be you want to reshape back to wide format with `pivot_wider`?  (not clear without a small reproducible example)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237265/discussion-between-nasa313-and-akrun).

Comment: @nasa313 what i find it difficult to undersatnd is that you are `cbind`ing together 3 datasets, then select only the `1_`.  why you need `cbind` then

Comment: So do I run `f1` function first, then the `pmap`?

Comment: @nasa313 try the update

Comment: yes I did `cbind` the dataset, but I need to select the dataset in the order seen in `step VII`

Comment: @nasa313 i think you need `pivot_wider` as in the code I showed.  if you have different class_low/class_high filter change the `c(1, 1, 1)` to `c(1, 3, 5)` and `c(5, 8, 8)` or so

Comment: I ran your code, see the error I got  (refer to uploaded images)

Comment: @nasa313 is your column  names `1_date`, `1_cityID` etc instead of the ones you showed in 'data'

Comment: @nasa313 I would suggest to just comment out the code after the first line in the function i.e. `out <- readr::read_csv(filenm); print(colnames(out))` for debugging

Comment: @nasa313 based on the error you showed, it is from the `select` step i.e. `dplyr::select(date:gender, savings_month1:savings_month3)`  Please check the column names to be sure whether these columns exist or not

Comment: Thanks for catching the error,  I fixed it. we are almost done. one last thing. The sequence of` savings_month` columns after `gender_1` column are a little bit off (refer to the image in update 2 in  the code) . Can you make the columns follow this sequence :  `savings_month1_1`, `savings_month1_2`,`savings_month1_5`, `savings_month2_1`,`savings_month2_2`,`savings_month2_5`,`savings_month3_1`,`savings_month3_2,savings_month3_5`. Thanks

Comment: @nasa313 Can you change it to ` savings_month1_1:savings_month3_5` (updated the function)

Comment: another error after changing `savings_month1:savings_month3`  (see update 3 in the code)

Comment: @nasa313 that seems to be related to the files.  i.e. check the `files`.  Do you have more than 3 files as earlier mentioned i..e you are providing more or less files than the length of other input parameters

Comment: Thanks so far, you have been to kind. I will get to you in a few hours. let me go through the files.